# AngularJS UI-Router: How do I get a "parent" state to all of the states?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI router and I want to make my routes have a base, that being the user slug. For example, a user by the name of John Doe will have a slug john-doe and in the URL it shows as `/@john-doe`.

I'm trying to set the `user` state as a base for all other states but I can't seem to find out how.

I want it such that once a user is logged in, he/she is redirected to `/@slug/home`, and every state url after that will be preceeded with `/@slug`, so a profile state (user.profile) should have the url `/@slug/profile`.

I tried making it by having a `$state.go('user', {'slug' : $rootScope.currentUser.slug');` in my login function and it works but I would have to set something like that to every single link on the app so I know there must be a better way to do this.. plus that wouldn't work well because if the slug is added on the click event then once a page is refreshed or something then that parameter is gone, which is not ideal cause it'd just leave a `/@/profile` with the slug missing.

Here is my `app.js`:

```
    .state('signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        data: {
            permissions: {
                except: ['isLoggedIn'],
                redirectTo: 'user'
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
        controller: 'SignupController as signup'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        data: {
            permissions: {
                except: ['isLoggedIn'],
                redirectTo: 'user'
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController as login'
    })
    .state('user', {
        url: '/@:slug/home',
        data: {
            permissions: {
                except: ['anonymous'],
                redirectTo: 'login'
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController as home',
        params: {
            slug: null
        }
    })
    .state('user.profile', {
        url: '/@:slug/profile',
        data: {
            permissions: {
                except: ['anonymous'],
                redirectTo: 'login'
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileController as profile',
        params: {
            slug: null
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `parent` property of all child states to "user"? Alternatively you can name your child states "user.signup", "user.login", etc.